# How does loom screen record without asking for permission to capture the screen?

Tags: webrtc

Loom's chrome extension can record your screen with "one click record".

Normally, to capture someone's screen, the browser will display a "do you want to share your screen" modal.

How does Loom achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an *extension*, not just a web page. When you installed it, Chrome showed you the things it would have access to, and you accepted that by continuing with the installation:

[image]

Extensions have very a different permissions model than web pages, because there's that explicit, user-driven installation step.

Answer (score 0):

They have some iframe gome going on to work across permissions, Particularly for camera and mic on the content side. Permission for screen recording is generally handled when you are selecting the screen and letting the browser know which screen to record.